# Solving a Non-linear coupled differential equation with complex field

Tags: differential-equations, nonlinear

[image]

I am interested to numerically solve this non-linear coupled equation so I have written following code

```
E1 = Sqrt[1 + (del0)^2];
del0 = 1.5;
del1 = 1.5;
a = 1.5
a1 = 1.5
sol = NDSolve[{D[A[x, y, t], t] == 
    E1 - (1 + I*del0)*A[x, y, t] - (Abs[B[x, y, t]])^2 + 
     I*a*Laplacian[A[x, y, t], {x, y}], 
   D[B[x, y, t], t] == 
    A[x, y, t]*Conjugate[B[x, y, t]] - (1 + I*del1)*B[x, y, t] + 
     I*a1*Laplacian[B[x, y, t], {x, y}], A[x, y, 0] == 1.5, 
   B[x, y, 0] == 0.25, A[5, y, t] == A[-5, y, t], 
   A[x, 5, t] == A[x, -5, t], B[5, y, t] == B[-5, y, t], 
   B[x, 5, t] == B[x, -5, t]}, {A, B}, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, {t, 0, 
   10000}, Rule[MaxSteps, 1000]]
```

Is this method is fine,as A and B are complex. Also I am interested to see the time evolution of the output.

Comment: yes but ReA and ImA can be plotted. But I am interested in AbsA. Also result for plot is a flat surface which is not coinciding with the desired form.

Comment: Use `Abs[]` function.
`Plot[Abs[(A/.sol[[1]])[x0, y0, t]], {t, 10, 100}, PlotRange -> All]`

Comment: I have edited your old question. check it.